# The session is not working when I send request from ionic 5 projects on the IOS platform but it works fine on Android

Tags: java, angular, session, ionic-framework, ionic5

In the backend, I am using a Java server and connect it to the ionic 5 project

```
    if(origin.contains("ionic")) {
        httpresponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "ionic://localhost");
    } else {
        httpresponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
    }
```

and I am sending  requests from angular HTTP with credentials

```
ths.http.post(SOME_URL,data.toString(),{headers:headers,withCredentials:true }).subscribe(...)
```

It works fine with android
but when I switch to IOS It does not work because the session is not preserved for consequent request

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring the CORS policy all together (just for now):

```java
httpresponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: I tried to add * it gave me CORS error on android and IOS